# Can't store a pdf file in a MySql table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I need to store a pdf file in MySql. Whether I use `escape_string` or not, I always get the same error

```
b_blob = open(dir + fname_only, "rb")
myblob = b_blob.read() ####<-  b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xaa\xab\xac\xad\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (Apache FOP Version 0.94)\
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect( usual stuff )
        cursor =conn.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)
        newblob = conn._cmysql.escape_string(myblob)
        query = """INSERT INTO `mytable` (`storing`) VALUES('%s')""" %(newblob)
        cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as exc: 
        Functions.error_handler(exc); 
        return
b_blob.close()
```

...MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n%\xaa\xab\xac\xad\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (Apache FOP Version 0.94)\n/Creation' at line 1

Comment: could you just store the pdf in a folder structure and just put a pointer in the DB?

Comment: Although possible I would not recommend this approach. It is better to store the PDFs in a central storage location, with a unique name (e.g. randomly generated hex value), and point to the file path.

Comment: No, because I download that type of file in a temporary area, I store it in Mysql then delete it. It is a procedure that I have been following for several years and with PHP it has always worked without problems and since I am transporting everything in pyhton I would like to keep the same functionality

Comment: Can you print out your `query` variable please?

Comment: `INSERT INTO `mytable` (`storing`) VALUES('b'%PDF-1.4\\n%\xaa\xab\xac\xad\\n4 0 obj\\n<<\\n/Producer (Apache FOP Version 0.94)\\n/CreationDate (D:20221012134756+02\\\'00\\\')\\n>>\\nendobj\\n5 0 obj\\n<< /N 3\\n/Length 10 0 R\\n/Filter /FlateDecode \\n>>\\nstream\\nx\x9c\x9d\x96wXS\\\xe7\x1e\\\xc7\\\xdfsN\\\xf6`$!l\x08{\x86\xa5@\\0\x91\x11\xa6\x80\x0c\xd9\xa2\x10\x92\\0\x01\x12 $\x0c\\\xf7@T\xb0\xa2\xa8\\\xc8R\x04)\x8aX\xb0Z\x86\xd4\x89(\x0e\x8a\\\xe2\\\xde\\rR\x04\x94Z\xac\\\xe2\\\xc2\\\xd1D\x9e\xa7\\\xf5\\\xf6\\\xf6\\\xde\\\xdb\\\xdb\\\xef\x1f\\\xe7|\x9e\....`

Comment: Have you tried using a "prepared cursor" that uses prepared statements in the background for passing parameters as true parameters to mysql as opposed to using string interpolation?

Comment: Isn't it what I wrote in the original message? And I'm pretty sure it wont solve the problem signalled below. Of course I hope to be wrong but actually don't understand

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your problem is arriving from the quotes at the start of your string. I would consider putting double quotes around the newblob variable. Should look like this.

```
query = """INSERT INTO `mytable` (`storing`) VALUES("%s")""" %(newblob)
```

Comment: get an error after x88 due to a double quote, I suppose. Now the problem is how to escape it? Tried with `myblob = conn._cmysql.escape_string(myblob)` but only backslashes are escaped and after the escape I always receive the error
`b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xaa\xab\xac\xad\n4 0 obj\n<<\n/Producer (Apache FOP Version 0.94)\n/CreationDate (D:20221012134756+02\'00\')\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<< /N 3\n/Length 10 0 R\n/Filter /FlateDecode .....\xce\x88"\x97\xe2<\x01?_\xce\xd7\xe5l\x9c)\x15\n\xe4\xfcF\x11+\xe4s\xe49\xa0H\n\xbb\x84\xcfM\`